# Unity random.range value not same as last value

Tags: unity

Quick one,

Currently using Unity Random.Range to set a var with the value of an enum state.

State has 4 possible values, up, down, left,right. I call it like :

```
currentState = (StateType)Random.Range(0, 3);
```

This gets set at certain conditions.

My issue is though I don't want the new setting to be the same as the current one.

I have taken a look at the random.range on the API but haven't found anything useful.

Is there an easy way to basically say "randomize but not the same as the current state"

EDIT:

Currently im using a while loop.

```
while (currentState == LastState)
{
    currentState = (StateType)Random.Range(0, 3);
}
```

Is there anything i can do to remove the while loop?

Comment: I think it's fine. What's wrong with "while"?

Comment: although in probable, the fact that I'm asking to randomize again seems silly to me, as in it "could" randomize to one state multiple times in a row. So i was wondering is there a way to rather omit from the range rather than request to randomize all over again.

Comment: By the way, can you edit the title so it better matches what are you asking for? For future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, choose from range 1 unit smaller and if the result is greater or equal to current, add 1 to it.

```
var newState = Random.Range(0, (3 - 1)); //choose from range 1 smaller
currentState = (StateType)(newState >= (int)currentState ? newState + 1 : newState);
```

---

Edit: if you like really fancy syntax, you can also make it generic extension to `enum`s:

```
public static void Randomized<T>(this T except) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
   if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException("T must be an Enum type");

   var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
   int @new = Random.Range(0, values.Length - 1);

   return (T)values.GetValue(@new >= ((IList)values).IndexOf(except) ? @new + 1 : @new);
}
```

from now on you can call `Randomized()` on any enum type variable:

```
//declared somewhere in your class
private StateType stype = StateType.Anarchy;
// ...
//when you want to randomize it just do:
stype = stype.Randomized();
```

Comment: Oh that's clever... Nice solution! :-)

Comment: what happens if new state is 2 and current is 2? +1 makes 3 which is invalid in the range right?

Comment: Not looking good at all. Biggest value will (almost) never be returned and last+1 have double chance.

Comment: @Nikaas You are right, it is supposed to be GEQ , the point is - get a value from smaller range and "stretch" it over the current value.

Comment: I dont see how this fixs it? if the new and current are both 2, then it will still  do 2+1 for the value of 3 which in your range doesn't exist

Comment: @lemunk why it would be invalid? You said the range goes from (0, 3) so 3 is valid, i choose from range 1 smaller so *anything* from that range +1 must be valid.

Comment: oh sorry i see i thought this was an example, but yes making the range 1 less works.

Comment: Yes this new way looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just get a random state from the enum and place in the variable. Use something like this.

```
private static System.Random _Random = new System.Random(Environment.TickCount);

 public static T RandomEnumOf<T>(int exclusion)
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Must use Enum type");
                Array enumValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
                return (T)enumValues.GetValue(_Random.Next(enumValues.Length - exclusion));
            }
```

Usage : `EnumType enum = RandomEnumOf<EnumType>(0);` You can modify the exclusion param to fit your criteria.

Comment: nice answer i like it

Comment: If your exclsuion is 3, won't this always return 0? Likewise, if my exclusion is 1, then _Random.Next may still return 1, because it will return a value less than 3 (Length - 1)

Comment: I did say he needs to modify the exclusion param to something else. I just pasted my own code that works for my case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would just keep a list of random values to pick from.

Have some sort of index to use:

```
 int[] Range = new int[Max-1];
```

Then have a method to update this index when required:

```
int idx = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
{
    if (i == currentValue) continue;

    Range[idx] = i;
    idx++;
}
```

Then use this for your random:

```
int value = Range[Random.Range(1, Max-1)];
```